# VHDL - Conditional attribute declaration depending on a generic

Tags: vhdl

How do I write a code segment which would evaluate a generic and create (or not create) an attribute accordingly?

Example :

```
if G_MY_GENERIC then
    attribute my_attribute_typ : string;
    attribute my_attribute_typ of signal_having_an_attr : signal is "value";
else
    --nothing is created
end if;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to write something similar to that, but the attribute will only be visible in the scope of the generate statement.

```
g_something: if test_condition generate
   attribute my_attribute_typ : string;
   attribute an_attribute of my_attribute_typ: signal is "value";
begin
    -- attribute is visible in this scope

    p_my_process: process(clk)
    begin
        -- attribute is also visible here
    end process;
end generate;

-- but not here
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead you have to use something like the following to conditionally set an attribute (cumbersome, but achieves the result):

```
  signal asvRam : svRam_at(0 to gc_nFifoDepth-1) := (others => (others => '0'));

  type svStr_at is array(boolean) of string(0 to 10);
  constant c_svRamStyle : svStr_at := (false => "           ", true => "distributed");
  attribute ram_style : string;
  attribute ram_style of asvRam : signal is c_svRamStyle(gc_bDistributedRam);
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, since this does not limit the scope of the attribute. It works with Vivado at least.

Comment: As the author of the other answer, I agree

Answer (score 2):

We talked more generalized conditional compilation in the [IEEE VHDL Working Group](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/WebHome).  The debate was heated.  Some wanted a compile time approach (similar to 'C') and some an elaboration time approach.  Compile time approach works well in C because constants are also compile time objects, however, in VHDL, a compile time approach will not understand things in the VHDL environment, and hence, using a generic is not an option.  OTOH, the compile time option would probably give you vendor name, tool type (simulator, synthesis, ...), ...

I have added your code as a requirement to the proposal page.  It is at: http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/ConditionalCompilation

If you are willing to share additional insight on your application, I would like to add that to the proposal also.

Comment: I wished to declare a different RAM Style attribute name depending on the technology used. Altera use 'ramstyle' and Xilinx use 'ram_style'. Also, my request would have permitted to have a different default value for each attribute.

Comment: Oh and I slightly edited my example, you should check it out.

Answer (score -2):

Basically: this is exactly how VHDL does ***not*** work. In VHDL you declare your intent to use specific bits of hardware, and then the synthesizer attempts to connect those bits of hardware. Any semblance of dynamically creating hardware like `for ... generate` loops are essentially just a *semblance*: syntactic sugar to take the pain away.

What you can do   is conditionally *assign* to signals/variables:

```
process (sig1, sig2, enable) is
begin
  if enable = '1'
  then
    out <= sig1;
  else
    out <= sig2;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: This is unhelpful. VHDL is a Turing-complete programming language. Admittedly, it's extremely painful to use it as such, and is used almost exclusively for hardware specification, but that doesn't alter the fact you can use it for more than that, just as long as you're not expecting a synthesis tool to do anything with your program.

Comment: @Ollie ... you may be surprised just how well modern synth tools do with "programming" styles of VHDL. Sure there are constraints - static loop bounds - but for example, procedures and functions can be used to simplify a complex state machine, and synthesise perfectly well. I find I can take a chunk of (suitable) C or Ada, transcode it into VHDL, and synthesise it. The art then - ironically - comes in extracting serialism out of the parallel VHDL code (turning it into a state machine) to keep the HW size down...